# How to check any two parameters of a function are null

Tags: java, function, parameters, coding-style

Suppose I have a function that takes three parameters. Of course I could check that any two parameters of this function is null in this way.

```
returnType function(p1, p2, p3){

  if((p1 == null && p2 == null) || (p2 == null && p3 == null) || (p3== null && p1 == null)){
       return;    
   }

}
```

But this is rather cumbersome and wouldn't scale for larger number of parameters.

What would be the elegant way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way you suggest here as cumbersome won't work regardless of being cumbersome.

Comment: i know that, was just being shorter. I didn't write it following a language exactly as you can see.

Comment: Please use real code when you ask a question.

Comment: (DUPLICATE)A better formated question which is answered is in link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
returnType function(p1, p2, p3){
   Object[] args = {p1, p2, p3};
   if(Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(args), null) >= 2) {
        return;
   }
}
```

Comment: You should test as `>= 2`.

Comment: I thought the poster wanted to check if _exactly_ two parameters are null but then realized that's not the case. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: If you couple your approach with var args... You have the best solution in my opinion. +1

Answer (score 4):

> But this is rather cumbersome and wouldn't scale for larger number of parameters.

Moreover, this wouldn't compile. You need to add comparison with `null` for each parameter, like this:

```
if((p1 == null && p2 == null )
|| (p2 == null && p3 == null)
|| (p3 == null && p1 == null)) ...
```

If you need to scale to a larger number of parameters, do this:

```
int count = 0;
if (p1 == null) count++;
if (p2 == null) count++;
if (p3 == null) count++;
// ... and so on
if (count >= 2) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe restructure the method to pass a `List<Object>` or similar and then iterate the list to check the number of nulls.

Answer (score 2):

Pass your parameter as 
`public int someMethod(Object... param){// your code }`

You will get the param as array of Object, then iterate through array to check nulls. As soon as your count reaches 2, break the loop and declare a failure.

```
static int check(Object... param)
{
   int count= 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < param.length; i++)
        // check param[i] and increase count
   if(param[i] == null){
      count++;
   }
   // return count, this is the number of null parameters to the function.
   return count;
}
```

Edit 1:

If you are new to variable arguments in java, I would recommend to read https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/04/19/varargs.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I fixed it and improved the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

A smart solution with Java 5 is a varargs validation function.

You can create an utility validation function which takes varargs Object arguments, and check if they are all not null.

Then you can iterate on the array and stop the cycle when you find more than two parameters are null.

```
boolean validate(int maxNull, Object... params) {
    int count = 0;
    if (params == null) {
        return true;
    }
    for (Object param : params) {
        if (param == null) {
            count++;
        }
        if (count >= maxNull) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Using this utility function you can check all the parameters and also change the strategy of the test when you'll find a more efficient one.

Comment: Shouldn't return `true` when `params` is `null`.

Comment: I agree, Ravi: that's a corner case that depends on the needs. Throwing a null pointer exception can be another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can always conduct your code in a `try` block and `catch` `NullPointerException`

```
String foo(Object p1, Object p2, Object p3){
  String bar;
  try {
       bar = p1.toString() + p2.toString();
       return bar;
   } catch (NullPointerException e) {
       return null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this just another way of checking,

```
boolean isAtleastTwoNull = (p1==null )? (p2== null || p3==null): (p2==null && p3==null);
```